# Remove an event listener on React component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I listen for window "scroll" events in one of my components.  However when the component is **unmounted**, the scroll event listener is not being removed.

The following error is produced when a scroll event occurs after the component has been unmounted:

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or
>   mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   TopNavDesktop component.

How can I properly remove this event listener?

**Example code:**

```
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      distanceScrolled: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }

  handleScroll(e){
    const distanceScrolled = e.srcElement.body.scrollTop;

    this.setState({ distanceScrolled: distanceScrolled });
  }

  render { ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you remove the listener, you're creating a new function reference.

`someFn.bind(this) === someFn.bind(this)` will evaluate to false.

Instead, save the function in your constructor and use that reference:

```
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      distanceScrolled: null
    }

    this.scrollFn = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFn);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollFn);
  }

  handleScroll(e){
    const distanceScrolled = e.srcElement.body.scrollTop;

    this.setState({ distanceScrolled: distanceScrolled });
  }

  render { ... } 
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised I didn't realize that `someFn.bind(this)` was creating a new reference.  Thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 3):

You should do this in this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.listener = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listener);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listener);
}
```

By invoking second time `this.handleScroll.bind(this)` in `componentWillUnmount` you creating new function instead of passing previous.